# Concurrent inserts into database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building a program that takes push data from six different sources and inserts the data into a database. Each source has its own function to execute the inserts as soon as they come, but all sources write to the same table.

I would have the following questions:

- If one source is currently writing to the table and another source begins to write at the same time is there any chance the inserts will block each other?
- The table is also constantly being used to read the data via a view that join some more tables to show the data, can this pose any problems?
- Currently each source has its own DB connection to write data, would it be better to have only one connection, or have each use its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If one source is currently writing to the table and another source
>   begins to write at the same time is there any chance the inserts will
>   block each other?

It depends on the indexes.  If the index keys have the same or contiguous values, you may see short=term blocking for the duration of the transaction.

> The table is also constantly being used to read the data via a view
>   that join some more tables to show the data, can this pose any
>   problems?

It depends on the isolation level.  No blocking will occur if:

- `SELECT` queries are running in `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level and
  the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHSOT` database option is turned on
- the `SELECT` queries don't touch uncommitted data
- the `SELECT` queries run in `READ_UNCOMMITTED` isolation level

Even if blocking does occur, it may be short-lived if the `INSERT` transactions are short.

> Currently each source has its own DB connection to write data, would
>   it be better to have only one connection, or have each use its own?

Depends on the problem you are trying to solve.  A single connection will ensure inserts don't block/deadlock with each other but might not be an issue anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below inline answer

If one source is currently writing to the table and another source begins to write at the same time is there any chance the inserts will block each other?

> In this case another resource will wait for it.(Insert will be in waiting state for next one)

The table is also constantly being used to read the data via a view that join some more tables to show the data, can this pose any problems?

> No problem.

Currently each source has its own DB connection to write data, would it be better to have only one connection, or have each use its own?

> Its better to have one DB connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Block "each other" i.e. dead-lock is not possible.
2. No problem. Only if `select` is too slow, it can delay next insert.
3. No problem with different connections.